# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered. Windows+bash

Tags: pytorch

When starting neural network training, at the time of training it gives an error:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so t
he stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
I have nvidia geforce 1650.

An attempt to restart the video card, and CUDA did not help, I want the learning process to continue normally.
[image]

Comment: pytorch-2.0.1,CUDA-11.8

Comment: OOM = out of memory

Comment: any ideas how to solve the problem?